# How to verify sks-keyservers HKPS certificate?

Tags: security, gnupg, pgp, public-key-encryption

I’m trying to make sense of how PGP is supposed to be used securely, but coherent and helpful information on the subject is surprisingly hard to find.

So, SKS keyservers provide [their HKPS certificate](https://sks-keyservers.net/verify_tls.php) along with these pieces of information:

1. Certificate download [link](https://sks-keyservers.net/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem)
2. OpenPGP signature download [link](https://sks-keyservers.net/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem.asc)
3. CRL download [link](https://sks-keyservers.net/ca/crl.pem) (certificate revocation list??)
4. Certificate’s fingerprint: `79:1B:27:A3:8E:66:7F:80:27:81:4D:4E:68:E7:C4:78:A4:5D:5A:17`
5. X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: `E4 C3 2A 09 14 67 D8 4D 52 12 4E 93 3C 13 E8 A0 8D DA B6 F3`

All I have on my side is `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.10` and internet access.

My questions are:

- How is each piece of information supposed to be used?
- How do I figure out, whose public key I should download from a keyserver separately (so that I don’t trust their website alone)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that you could skip the whole process entirely, because the SKS pool CA certificate is bundled with recent GnuPG distributions – usually located at `/usr/share/gnupg/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem`.

Second, note that the usage of HKPS does not authenticate the data *held* by the pool. It is **only** a privacy measure (to prevent your whole keyring from being revealed by --refresh-keys). But actual PGP keyblocks retrieved from the keyservers still have to be verified the same way as you always would. That is, you **still must** verify each imported key's fingerprint, or rely on Web-of-Trust or GnuPG's tofu.db.

So when it comes to:

> How do I figure out, whose public key I should download from a keyserver separately (so that I don’t trust their website alone)?

If someone could have compromised the website to upload a fake CA.pem, they could have just as well uploaded a fake CA.pem.asc signature alongside it. And if someone could have inserted a fake public key into the website, they could have uploaded the same key to keyservers.

In other words, downloading someone's key separately from a keyserver does not provide any additional security. The keyserver doesn't stop anyone from uploading fake keys under the same name & email. Everything still boils down to verifying the key's fingerprint or Web-of-trust verification. If you don't have a fingerprint to verify against, you might obtain one by asking the owner.

(To know what *person* manages the SKS Pool, I'd say technical means are not sufficient. My approach would be to gather information from diverse sources, such as asking other people or checking web.archive.org, or asking on the GnuPG IRC channel (if you trust randoms on IRC). If you keep seeing the same "Kristian Fiskerstrand" person everywhere, that's probably the correct one.)

If you don't have **any** form of preexisting contact with the website's owner, your only option is to trust that the website is serving you legitimate information. (Fortunately your connection to it is authenticated by HTTPS and WebPKI, so you can rule out most MITM attacks – leaving only server compromise.)

You can perhaps check various snapshots in time of the website at web.archive.org (to see if the same key has been in place for the last few months or years).

> How is each piece of information supposed to be used?

The certificate's fingerprint and/or SPKI hash serve practically the same purpose as when websites offer plain SHA1 hashes alongside downloads. (Indeed the fingerprint is simply a SHA1 hash of the certificate minus its Base64 encoding.) You can use them *if* you trust the website... but then it's mostly redundant because you got the CA cert itself from the same website. It may prevent some accidental mistakes though.

To view the certificate's fingerprint (SHA1):

```
openssl x509 -in $file -noout -fingerprint -sha1
certtool --fingerprint < $file
cat $file | sed "/^-/d" | base64 -d | sha1sum
```

Viewing the X.509v3 Subject Key Identifier requires paying attention to the difference between *calculating* the SPKI hash yourself (as seen under "Other Information") versus merely looking at the one embedded in X.509 extensions (as seen under "Extensions"):

```
certtool -i < $file | grep -C3 "Public Key ID"
```

The CRL (certificate revocation list) is used by GnuPG's dirmngr to ensure that compromised keyserver certs cannot be reused until they expire. The CRL is signed by the CA, and I think dirmngr automatically downloads and refreshes it so you don't have to.

The signature is made by the website's owner, and can be used to verify the CA.pem file if you already have other means of verification for the owner's PGP key. Merely downloading it from the same website does not add much.

To verify the signature:

```
gpg --verify sks-keyservers.netCA.pem.asc
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for this informative response. I understand that most of what I’m asking about is unneeded, but still want to know for my own education. I have just one follow-up question: how exactly am I to check my downloaded cert against the fingerprint and SKI provided at the website?

Comment: Primary key fingerprint: [some 32 character hash]  gpg2 --verify $file.asc $file and also make sure the primary fingerprint matches EXACTLY what the site claims it should be